# Need a translation: Mathspeak to english

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Watching a video on multiple integration. Maybe its that the coffee has not kicked in but I am having trouble with understanding the graphing term "mapping". Can anyone put it in layman's terms or at least give me a geometric understanding?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Thank you for the link. Glad to know there are some folks who are polite enough to show an OP an explanation rather than just down vote and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally mapping=function.. That is, a relation satisfying:
$$xRy \land xRz \implies y=z.$$
As an analogy with an every-day map: If you hold a map and someone gives you the coordinates of some destination, you wouldn't want them to **map** to more than one point on the map..